# Fatal Error while download dependancies in Android Studio Arctic Fox

Tags: java, android, kotlin, build.gradle

when i have to go for Make Project then build.gradle file is showing fatal errors in sync files picture is shown below

[image]

Comment: This repository might use an outdated format... when I read "5 min, 23 sec", I'd have another question.

Comment: please consider to add more detail about what is wrong and try to post a log not a photos